# 'Dynamic' connection string for ms-access C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access, connection

I have an access database connected to my code via a connection string as shown:

```
connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Computing Project\Database.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;");
```

However I would like this app to be able to be installed on other devices, so I'm guessing the connection string has to be dynamic and change on each system. How would I use this in my code?

Comment: Reading the value from your config file instead of hard coding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an App.config to the solution with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCon" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Computing Project\Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"/ >
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then in code,

```
connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ToString());
```

PS: ConfigurationManager class is in assembly System.Configuration.
So please add a reference of this assembly before using it.

Comment: I have added the System.Configuration reference but when I use this code it says that I have invalid arguments? I use the name of my connection string in place of yours and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've missed to convert it to string. Please check updated answer

Comment: It worked thank you! Where would be the best place to put the database (folder wise) for when it comes to building the solution?

Comment: You're very welcome. Could you please mark my answer as accepted. Create a folder named App_Data in solution and include the file in it.